# Using existing human translations to aid machine translation to a new language

Tags: localization, machine-learning, translation, globalization, machine-translation

In the past, my company has used human, professional translators to translate our software from English into some 13 languages. It's expensive but the quality is high.

The application we're translating contains industry jargon. It also contains a lot of sentence fragments and single words which, out of context, are unlikely to be correctly translated.

I am wondering if there is a machine translation system or service that could use our existing professionally-generated translations to more accurately create a machine translation into any new language.

If an industry term, phrase or sentence fragment has been translated from en-US to es-AR, pt-BR, cs-CZ, etc., then couldn't those prior translations be used as a hint regarding what the correct word choice should be for some new language? They could be used, in a sense, to triangulate. At worst, they could be used to create a majority voting system (e.g. if 9 of 13 languages translated a phrase to the same thing in the new language, we go with it).

Is anyone aware of a machine translation service that works like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  A lot has changed in the decade since 2014.

Now, as of 2023, there are more than a dozen customizable cloud API providers, many of them self-serve.

For example, Google Translate launched customization in 2018, after launching [neural machine translation](https://machinetranslate.org/neural-machine-translation) in 2016, which made it a lot easier to offer.

From [machinetranslate.org/customisation](https://machinetranslate.org/customisation):

> 14 APIs support customisation.
>
> - [Amazon Translate](https://machinetranslate.org/amazon)
> - [Omniscien Technologies](https://machinetranslate.org/omniscien)
> - [Amazon Translate](https://machinetranslate.org/amazon)
> - [KantanMT](https://machinetranslate.org/kantanmt)
> - [Language Weaver](https://machinetranslate.org/language-weaver)
> - [Lilt](https://machinetranslate.org/lilt)
> - [Mirai Translator](https://machinetranslate.org/mirai)
> - [ModernMT](https://machinetranslate.org/modernmt)
> - [NpatMT](https://machinetranslate.org/npatmt)
> - [Omniscien Technologies](https://machinetranslate.org/omniscien)
> - [PangeaMT](https://machinetranslate.org/pangeamt)
> - [Phrase NextMT](https://machinetranslate.org/phrase-nextmt)
> - [Sunda Translator](https://machinetranslate.org/sunda)
> - [Tilde](https://machinetranslate.org/tilde)

The type of customization you describe, training with your own [parallel data](https://machinetranslate.org/parallel-data), is the most common.  These days it is usually achieved with [fine-tuning](https://machinetranslate.org/fine-tuning).

The basic types of customization that the major machine translation APIs offer are:

- [Fine-tuning](https://machinetranslate.org/fine-tuning) - Training a model with parallel data
- [Adaptive](https://machinetranslate.org/adaptive) - Similar to fine-tuning, but it updates on the fly
- [Glossaries](https://machinetranslate.org/glossaries) - Defining specific terminology
- [Formality](https://machinetranslate.org/formality) - Formal or informal 2nd person

There are also other methods of customization offered, like choosing a specific locale, like Canadian French, or a specific domain, like fashion.

There is basically a trade-off between simplicity and control - a lot of those methods are basically a parameter or a button click, but the engine can't even hope to reflect your style the way that a model fine-tuned on your training data can.

Warning: Even if an API supports customization, and that API is [integrated in your translation management system](https://machinetranslate.org/integrations), that integration does not necessarily support using your customized version of that API.  So before you invest time in customization, [check your TMS integration](https://machinetranslate.org/integrations) to be sure it'll actually let you access your custom machine translation.

For example, there is [no ModernMT integration in XTM](https://machinetranslate.org/xtm#api-support).  There is a Google Translate integration, but it supports customization only via fine-tuning, not via glossaries.

---

Full disclosure: I'm the founder of and a major contributor to Machine Translate, the non-profit foundation making machine translation more accessible to more people, with open information and community.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about tranlation systems, but such functionality -- custom translations for specific words -- will be offered by any commercial system, I guess. It is even possible with [google translate](https://translate.google.de/) by clicking on the book with the star on cover.

As a trivial non-invasive method, you could for each goal-language make up a dictionary [] the required terminology in the form `[word-as-is-translated, word-as-should-be-translated]`, where you have an `N:1` relationship (in one language multiple `word-as-is-translated` should be mapped to one `word-as-should-be-translated`. The words `word-as-is-translated` thereby depend on the actual translation system).

After preparing those dictionaries, you can simply search the translation result for those words and replace them with the desired words.